# Analog of $\operatorname{Var}[X] = E[X^2] - E^2[X] $ for random matrices

Tags: random-variables, random-matrices

For a scalar random variable, we have the identity:
$\operatorname{Var}[X] = E[X^2] - E^2[X] $

Is there a similar formula for $X$ being a random matrix? For sure, the covariance "matrix" would be a 4-dimensional tensor.

Comment: No reason for the variance to be a $4$-dimensional tensor. It is just the variance of each component.

Comment: But where would you encode $Cov(X_{i,j},X_{k,l})$ for $(i,j) \neq (k,l)$? This is why I thought it is four dimensional.

Comment: It's not clear that is a fundamental property you'd want in $\operatorname{Var}.$ Certainly, it isn't one for random numbers, since there is no interesting covariance between $X$ and $X.$